# mysql group_concat silex doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, silex

I'm currently working with Silex (PHP FW) + Doctrine. I need to get the users list where user belongs to various departments. When i use group_concat() i got error `QueryException in QueryException.php line 52: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 77: Error: Expected known function, got 'GROUP_CONCAT'` so when I google it, found that we have include the GroupConcat() library https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions but not provided information on how to load library to use it inside the `createQueryBuilder()`.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please provide a code example.

Comment: `$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$dataQuery = $qb->select('GROUP_CONCAT(ut.userTypeNames)')->from('user_types', 'ut')->leftjoin('user_type_mapping', 'utm' \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH 'ut.user_type_id' = 'utm.user_type_id)->where('utm.user_id = ', ':userId')->setParameter('userId',$userId)->groupby( 'utm.user_id');` is the sample code... When I used this CreateQueryBuilder() i'm getting the above mentioned error.